# Dependent picklist apex code for test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

How to write test class for dependent picklist apex code??

```
public String Country {get;set;}
    public String state {get;set;}
    public String city {get;set;}

    public List<SelectOption> getCountries()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('None','--- None ---'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('IND','INDIA'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('US','UNITED STATES'));
        return options;
    }
    public List<SelectOption> getStates()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        if(country == 'IND')
        {
        options.add(new SelectOption('NO','---None---'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('TN','Tamil Nadu'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('KL','Kerala'));
        }
         else if(country == 'US')
         {
        options.add(new SelectOption('NO','---None---'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('TX','TEXAS'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('IL','ILLINOIS'));
        }
        else if  (country == 'None')
        {
        options.add(new SelectOption('None','--- None ---'));
        }
        return options;

    }
     public List<SelectOption> getCities()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        if(state =='TN')
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption('NO','---None---'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('CHE','Chennai'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('CBE','Coimbatore'));
        }
         else if(state == 'KL')
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption('NO','---None---'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('COA','Coachin'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('ALP','Alleppi'));
        }
         else if(state == 'TX')
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption('NO','---None---'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('HUN','Huston'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('SNA','San Antonio'));
        }
         else if(state == 'IL')
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption('NO','---None---'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('CGO','Chicago'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('ATA','Atlanta'));
        }

        else if  (state == 'NO')
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption('None','--- None ---'));
        }
        return options;
    }
     public String Country1 {get;set;}
     public String state1 {get;set;}
     public String city1 {get;set;}

     public List<SelectOption> getCountries1()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('None','--- None ---'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('IND','INDIA'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('US','UNITED STATES'));
        return options;
    }
    public List<SelectOption> getStates1()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        if(country1 == 'IND')
        {
        options.add(new SelectOption('NO','---None---'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('TN','Tamil Nadu'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('KL','Kerala'));
        }
         else if(country1 == 'US')
         {
        options.add(new SelectOption('NO','---None---'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('TX','TEXAS'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('IL','ILLINOIS'));
        }
        else if  (country1 == 'None')
        {
        options.add(new SelectOption('None','--- None ---'));
        }
        return options;

    }
     public List<SelectOption> getCities1()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        if(state1 =='TN')
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption('NO','---None---'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('CHE','Chennai'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('CBE','Coimbatore'));
        }
         else if(state1 == 'KL')
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption('NO','---None---'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('COA','Coachin'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('ALP','Alleppi'));
        }
         else if(state1 == 'TX')
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption('NO','---None---'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('HUN','Huston'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('SNA','San Antonio'));
        }
         else if(state1 == 'IL')
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption('NO','---None---'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('CGO','Chicago'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('ATA','Atlanta'));
        }

        else if  (state1 == 'NO')
        {
            options.add(new SelectOption('None','--- None ---'));
        }
        return options;
    }
```

Comment: I am new to salesforce. I am getting confused in writing the test class.

Comment: sripuram -- the folks at SFSE love to help but it doesn't look like you've reviewed (or at least demonstrated that you've reviewed) the doc on testing controllers here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm?SearchType=Stem

Answer (score 2):

You need to test it much like you would any other test.  You need to set your country to a specific value.  Then you check that the states match as they should according to the country that was chosen.  So something like this

```
controller.Country = 'US';

for(SelectOption stateOpt : controller.getStates()){
      system.assertNotEquals('Tamil Nadu', stateOpt.getValue());
      system.assertNotEquals('Kerala', stateOpt.getValue());
}
```

Obviously, this is just psuedo-code and you will have to adjust it and expand it for some positive tests as well, but this should give you the idea of how to begin thinking about testing it.

Comment: Can u please explain it clearly. I am new to salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

```
@isTest
public class TestSample {

    public static testMethod void main(){
         PageReference pageRef = Page.dependentPicklist;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef); 
        sample s = new sample();
        s.getCountries();
        s.getCountries1();

        s.Country = 'US';
        for(SelectOption stateOpt : s.getStates()){
              system.assertNotEquals('Tamil Nadu', stateOpt.getValue());
              system.assertNotEquals('Kerala', stateOpt.getValue());
        }
        s.Country = 'IND';

        for(SelectOption stateOpt : s.getStates()){
              system.assertNotEquals('Tamil Nadu', stateOpt.getValue());
              system.assertNotEquals('Kerala', stateOpt.getValue());
        }
        s.Country = 'None';

        for(SelectOption stateOpt : s.getStates()){
              system.assertNotEquals('Tamil Nadu', stateOpt.getValue());
              system.assertNotEquals('Kerala', stateOpt.getValue());
        }
        s.Country1 = 'US';

        for(SelectOption stateOpt : s.getStates1()){
              system.assertNotEquals('Tamil Nadu', stateOpt.getValue());
              system.assertNotEquals('Kerala', stateOpt.getValue());
        }
        s.Country1 = 'IND';

        for(SelectOption stateOpt : s.getStates1()){
              system.assertNotEquals('Tamil Nadu', stateOpt.getValue());
              system.assertNotEquals('Kerala', stateOpt.getValue());
        }
        s.Country1 = 'None';

        for(SelectOption stateOpt : s.getStates1()){
              system.assertNotEquals('Tamil Nadu', stateOpt.getValue());
              system.assertNotEquals('Kerala', stateOpt.getValue());
        }
        s.state = 'NO';
        for(SelectOption cityOpt : s.getCities()){
              system.assertNotEquals('NO', cityOpt.getValue());               
        }
        s.state1 = 'NO';
        for(SelectOption cityOpt1 : s.getCities1()){
              system.assertNotEquals('NO', cityOpt1.getValue());               
        }
        s.state = 'TN';
        for(SelectOption cityOpt : s.getCities()){             
              system.assertNotEquals('COA', cityOpt.getValue());

        }
        s.state1 = 'TN';
        for(SelectOption cityOpt1 : s.getCities1()){             
              system.assertNotEquals('COA', cityOpt1.getValue());

        }
        s.state = 'KL';
        for(SelectOption cityOpt : s.getCities()){

              system.assertNotEquals('CBE', cityOpt.getValue());

        }
        s.state = 'TX';
        for(SelectOption cityOpt : s.getCities()){

              system.assertNotEquals('ALP', cityOpt.getValue());

        }
        s.state = 'IL';
        for(SelectOption cityOpt : s.getCities()){

              system.assertNotEquals('HUN', cityOpt.getValue());

        }
        s.state1 = 'KL';
        for(SelectOption cityOpt1 : s.getCities1()){

              system.assertNotEquals('CBE', cityOpt1.getValue());

        }
        s.state1 = 'TX';
        for(SelectOption cityOpt1 : s.getCities1()){

              system.assertNotEquals('ALP', cityOpt1.getValue());

        }
        s.state1 = 'IL';
        for(SelectOption cityOpt1 : s.getCities1()){

              system.assertNotEquals('HUN', cityOpt1.getValue());

        }

    }
}
```